# Conditional operator?

Tags: c#, .net, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

```
var discount = (i == 1) ? definition.SecondPetDiscount ?? definition.AdditionalPetDiscount :
               (i == 2) ? definition.ThirdPetDiscount ?? definition.AdditionalPetDiscount :
               definition.AdditionalPetDiscount;
```

Could you any one give me an explanation of this code snippet? I know about the ternary operator. But the above is not like that.

The normal ternary operator looks like this:

```
PaidDate = ( paidDate == null ? DateTime.Now : paidDate);
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx ?

Comment: This is a combination of multiple "conditional" and "null-coalescing" operators. Just add brackets until it makes sense :)

Comment: FYI it's properly called the conditional operator not the ternary operator

Comment: Maybe this will explain it better, your same example
 `DateTime? paidDate = null;
  var date = paidDate ?? DateTime.Now;`
You can interpret it as "if paidDate is not null, then return its value, otherwise return DateTime.Now. Notice that the first argument needs to be Nullable, in this case `DateTime?`

Comment: `Sampath` are you familiar with `inline ifelse` this is similar to that basically `return left side if true, else, rightside, else leftside, else right side, else default` that's how I do it mentally

Comment: Since the expression has very few parentheses it is essential to note that the null coalescing operator `??` has _higher_ precedence than the conditional operator `? :`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`?:` is the ternary operator. `??` is the null-coalescing operator. It is used to return the first expression that is not null.

The snippet you posted is making use of both operators. It is equivalent to the following `if/else` construct:

```
if (i == 1)
{
    if (definition.SecondPetDiscount != null)
    {
        discount = definition.SecondPetDiscount;
    }
    else
    {
        discount = definition.AdditionalPetDiscount;
    }
}
else if (i == 2)
{
    if (definition.ThirdPetDiscount != null)
    {
        discount = definition.ThirdPetDiscount;
    }
    else
    {
        discount = definition.AdditionalPetDiscount;
    }
}
else
{
    discount = definition.AdditionalPetDiscount;
}
```

In that snippet they are chaining together multiple ternary operations. It is also sometimes useful to chain together multiple null-coalescing operations, e.g. `var foo = a ?? b ?? c`.

Answer (score 4):

That's the null-coalescing operator in C#.  It is a shortcut that returns the left side (if the left side is not null) and otherwise returns the right side

Answer (score 4):

This is a mix.

In this statement, there are two conditional (ternary) operations, as well as the [null coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator.

The second "option" of the first ternary operation is an entire ternary operation itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confused with the null coalescing operator, or the `??`

```
definition.ThirdPetDiscount ?? definition.AdditionalPetDiscount
```

it means that if `definition.ThirdPetDiscount` is null, than use `definition.AdditionalPetDiscount`

the ternary operator around that behaves like a regular ternary operator.  the null-coalescing operator is just nested inside of it, and you also have 1 ternary operator nested in a second ternary operator

Answer (score 0):

```
var discount = (i == 1) ? definition.SecondPetDiscount ?? definition.AdditionalPetDiscount :
               (i == 2) ? definition.ThirdPetDiscount ?? definition.AdditionalPetDiscount :
               definition.AdditionalPetDiscount;
```

Of course, the `(bool) ? code : code` pattern translates to an if - else block.

So we get

```
var discount;
if( i==1 )
{
    discount = definition.SecondPetDiscount ?? definition.AdditionalPetDiscount;
}
else if( i==2 )
{
    discount = definition.ThirdPetDiscount ?? definition.AdditionalPetDiscount;
}
else
{
    discount = definition.AdditionalPetDiscount;
}
```

`object ?? object` is the null coalescing ternary operator.  What this does is it will take the first non-null object in the coalescing and return it.  There can be any number of objects in the list.

So the `var discount` here is set to `definition.AdditionalPetDiscount` if the 2nd or 3rd pet discount is null, or if i is not 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

If i is 1 then discount will be set to definition.SecondPetDiscount unless that is null, in which case it will be set to definition.AdditionalPetDiscount.

If i is 2 then discount will be set to definition.ThirdPetDiscount unless that is null, in which case it will be set to definition.AdditionalPetDiscount.

If i is neither 1 nor 2 then it will be set to definition.AdditionalPetDiscount.